# How to read a config file which is located at project path in Android?

Tags: android, config, read-write

In my application there are some configuration data, such as ipaddress, portno, title and etc. I want to keep these data in phone and out of the application in config.And I will read from and write to this file.How can I do that?If not what can you suggest me to do that?

IPAddress=127.0.0.1
Port=1234

Comment: May I ask why it is important to keep this data separated from your application ?

Comment: Because IP address to connect my webservice can change.Is it possible or not.Is what I ask absurt?

Comment: Of course, yes, it's possible, but that doesn't require external storage.  Do you mean to ask if it is possible to include storage which is not compiled, but changeable ?

Comment: does my answer, re: shared preferences address the problem, or do you really need external file storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read and write files, and in reading from a file, you can set a variable.  I'll assume that you're capable of handling all of the gui related tasks involved with prompting users for input, as that is really a different question.

My explanation is largely from the Android Developer Docs, where you can read more fully at this link [Using External Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

First, we'll assume that your user wants to load the settings file from the Downloads directory. You'll need permissions to use the external storage, add the following to your manifest, between the `<manifest>` tags:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Before you try to access the file, you'll want to check the state of your system's external storage, to see if you can read from it

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
boolean isReadable =  (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
```

If the external storage is readable, you can get a hold of an external file, we're going to call it "settings" within the Downloads directory :

```
private static final SETTINGS_FILENAME = "settings";
...
public File getSettingsFile() {
    // Get the directory for the user's public downloads directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), SETTINGS_FILENAME);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "The settings file does not exist");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Now, you have access to the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) that you emailed to your client.  You will use the standard interface, which I linked to, to read the file and internalize its settings.

Again, this is all just sourced from the developer docs, with slight modification.  I hope that that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I know the shared preferences.But While the application  starts  for the first time,is shared prefs empty?How can I fill it.The service application(WCF service) which android application can talk can be on different customers.

Comment: @kkk Can you create a settings activity where your customer can configure the server and port?

Comment: I think it won't meet my request.Because the application have a login mechanism.Username and password confirmation which is in related wcf service is required.

Comment: @kkk Until you describe your requirements fully, I won't be able to help you.  Please describe what you need in clear terms in your original post.  Otherwise, the goal post will keep moving as I attempt to answer.

Comment: @kkk do you need to have the port and server set when you build the apk ?

Comment: I don't need to have port and server information when I build the apk.If I set this information before building apk, many different apk occurs for multiple customer.I want to choose this way(using config file) to avoid to create multiple instance.I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Yes,  but,  before the customer downloads the apk,  you want to set these variables for them.   Correct?

Comment: Yes I understand what you said,but I dont upload the application to google play.This will be  a commercial application.I will send the apk and config file to customers in specially

Comment: @kkk I've updated the answer to deal with files.  Let me know what you think

Comment: I think this will probably help me.Thank you very much for your answer and support.I will accept your answer.